# How can I remove asset metadata and compress the original rendition in a workflow?

Tags: aem, dam

I am trying to strip off the metadata from the original rendition of a uploaded image in DAM or compress it to reduce the size.

Are there any AEM out of the box APIs to accomplish this? I am trying to put the behaviour in a workflow process step in AEM 6.2.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for the corrections. Any thoughts/views on this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way for modifying DAM metadata is to use custom workflows.

If you are trying to modify the meta-data persisted within the file (for example some image files have location and copyright information) then you will need to use one of many API's available in the libraries shipped with AEM or use 3rd party libraries.

Alternatively, if you want to change the meta data persisted with you DAM asset, you will need to use your custom workflow to update/modify the meta data that is extracted from the DAM assets.

Either way, a lot of this depends on what metadata you are planning to extract or modify and this will have an impact on whether you can use builtin libs or 3rd party libs.

Comment: I am trying to extract most of the EXIF and Photoshop metadata fields persisted within the file itself and exploring Apache Commons Imaging library thereby reducing the image sizes and improving the page load times. Do you know any other well known 3rd party / builtin libraries  for  similar purpose? Thanks for sharing your view.

Comment: Apache Commons Imaging is good enough for what you are doing and a lot of Adobe tools use it so I can't recommend anything (open source) which will be better than that. I have seen it being used a lot in the field and so far no complaints.

Comment: Any thoughts on image compression, I am exploring ImageMagick API so that I can save a few more kilobytes by compressing the image.

Comment: **Opinionated answer disclaimer** In my experience the different libraries give different results on various images. For example, a library that compresses 90% of images as expected may fail on 10% of other images unexpectedly and some other library will give you the desired results. This is not a scientific answer that you might expect so test carefully and be prepared for plan B's.